# Cannot toggle checkboxes on grid with a selectall checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox, devexpress

I want to be able to select/unselect checkboxes for a specific column in a grid.

It gets an error inside the JS "onUPCSelectAll" function on the eval statement as follows:
**JS runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'SetChecked'**

During debugging, I am able to see that my id value is:

```
$(this)[0].id = "PrintCallbackPanel_selectAllUPCCheckBox"
```

My source code does indeed have this particular id set up, but, you can see where the id value actually places an "_S" onto the end of the control name.

Select/Unselect all UPC rows

The "SetChecked" method produces the following:

```
eval($(this)[0].id).SetChecked = function(isChecked) {
  this.SetCheckState(isChecked ? ASPxClientCheckBoxCheckState.Checked : ASPxClientCheckBoxCheckState.Unchecked);
 }
```

and finally, the full line produces an undefined value

```
?eval($(this)[0].id).SetChecked(s.GetChecked());
undefined
```

**HTML:**

```
<td style="padding-right: 10px;">
    <dx:ASPxCheckBox ID="selectAllUPCCheckBox" runat="server" Text="Select/Unselect all UPC rows" TextAlign="Right" ClientSideEvents-CheckedChanged="onUPCSelectAll" AutoPostBack="false" />
</td>
<td style="padding-right: 10px;">
    <dx:ASPxCheckBox ID="selectAllMPCCheckBox" runat="server" Text="Select/Unselect all MPC rows" TextAlign="Right" ClientSideEvents-CheckedChanged="onMPCSelectAll" AutoPostBack="false" />
</td>
```

**HTML Grid:**

```
<dx:ASPxCallbackPanel ID="PrintCallbackPanel" ClientInstanceName="PrintClientCallbackPanel" runat="server" OnCallback="PrintCallbackPanel_Callback" ShowLoadingPanel="false">
        <ClientSideEvents EndCallback="OnEndCallback" />
        <PanelCollection>
            <dx:PanelContent>
                <dx:ASPxLoadingPanel ID="MainASPxLoadingPanel" ClientInstanceName="MainASPxClientLoadingPanel" runat="server" Theme="BlackGlass">
                    <Image Width="50px" Height="50px"></Image>
                    <Border BorderColor="Blue" BorderStyle="Inset" BorderWidth="3px" />
                </dx:ASPxLoadingPanel>
                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="auto-style2">
                            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="searchTable" runat="Server">
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="padding-right: 10px;">
                                        <dx:ASPxLabel ID="lblSearchField" runat="server" Font-Bold="true" Text="Search By:" />
                                    </td>
                                    <td style="padding-right: 10px;">
                                        <dx:ASPxComboBox ID="FieldNameASPxComboBox" ClientInstanceName="FieldNameClientASPxComboBox" runat="server" ValueType="System.Int16" Theme="PlasticBlue" Style="margin-left: 0px">
                                            <Items>
                                                <dx:ListEditItem Text="Model" Value="0" Selected="true" />
                                                <dx:ListEditItem Text="PO" Value="1" />
                                            </Items>
                                            <ClientSideEvents ValueChanged="FieldNameChanged" />
                                        </dx:ASPxComboBox>
                                    </td>
                                    <td style="padding-right: 10px;">
                                        <dx:ASPxComboBox ID="FieldMethodASPxComboBox" ClientInstanceName="FieldMethodClientASPxComboBox" runat="server" ValueType="System.Int16" Theme="PlasticBlue" Width="100px">
                                            <Items>
                                                <dx:ListEditItem Text="Starts With" Value="0" Selected="true" />
                                                <dx:ListEditItem Text="Is Exactly" Value="1" />
                                                <dx:ListEditItem Text="Contains" Value="2" />
                                            </Items>
                                        </dx:ASPxComboBox>
                                    </td>
                                    <td style="padding-right: 10px;">
                                        <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="SearchTextASPxTextBox" ClientInstanceName="SearchTextClientASPxTextBox" runat="server" Width="250px" Theme="PlasticBlue" AutoCompleteType="None">
                                            <ValidationSettings ValidationGroup="CS" Display="Dynamic" ErrorDisplayMode="None">
                                                <RequiredField IsRequired="true" ErrorText="" />
                                            </ValidationSettings>
                                        </dx:ASPxTextBox>
                                    </td>
                                    <td style="padding-right: 10px;">
                                        <dx:ASPxButton ID="btnSearch" Text="Search" ClientInstanceName="btnSearchClient" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" ValidationGroup="CS" Theme="PlasticBlue" AutoPostBack="false">
                                            <ClientSideEvents Click="function (s,e) { DoSearch(); }" />
                                        </dx:ASPxButton>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="auto-style3">
                                        <dx:ASPxButton ID="btnClear" Text="Clear" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" AutoPostBack="false" Theme="PlasticBlue">
                                            <ClientSideEvents Click="function (s,e) {document.location.reload(true); }" />
                                        </dx:ASPxButton>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="6" style="height: 5px;"></td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" runat="server" id="selectionTable">
                        <tr>
                            <td style="padding-right: 10px;" class="auto-style4">
                                <dx:ASPxLabel ID="lblLabelSize" runat="server" Text="Label Size: "></dx:ASPxLabel>
                            </td>
                            <td style="padding-right: 10px;">
                                <dx:ASPxComboBox ID="ddlLabelSize" ClientInstanceName="lblLabelSizeClient" CausesValidation="false" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false" Theme="PlasticBlue">
                                    <Items>
                                        <dx:ListEditItem Text="Large" Value="0" Selected="true" />
                                        <dx:ListEditItem Text="Small" Value="1" />
                                    </Items>
                                    <ValidationSettings ValidationGroup="CS" Display="Dynamic" ErrorDisplayMode="None">
                                        <RequiredField IsRequired="true" ErrorText="" />
                                    </ValidationSettings>
                                </dx:ASPxComboBox>
                            </td>
                            <td style="padding-right: 10px;">
                                <dx:ASPxCheckBox ID="selectAllUPCCheckBox" runat="server" Text="Select/Unselect all UPC rows" TextAlign="Right"
                                    ClientSideEvents-CheckedChanged="onUPCSelectAll" Enabled="false"
                                    AutoPostBack="false" />
                            </td>
                            <td style="padding-right: 10px;">
                                <dx:ASPxCheckBox ID="selectAllMPCCheckBox" runat="server" Text="Select/Unselect all MPC rows" TextAlign="Right"
                                    ClientSideEvents-CheckedChanged="onMPCSelectAll" Enabled="false"
                                    AutoPostBack="false" />
                            </td>
                            <td style="padding-right: 10px;">
                                <dx:ASPxButton ID="btnPrint" Text="Print" runat="server" ClientInstanceName="btnPrintClient" CausesValidation="false" ValidationGroup="CS" Theme="PlasticBlue" AutoPostBack="false" Enabled="false">
                                    <ClientSideEvents Click="function (s,e) { PerformCallback('1:'); btnPrintClient.disabled = true; btnSearchClient.disabled = true; }" />
                                </dx:ASPxButton>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="6" style="height: 5px;"></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <dx:ASPxGridView ID="LabelASPxGridView"
                                    ClientInstanceName="LabelClientASPxGridView"
                                    runat="server"
                                    Caption="Label Printing"
                                    Theme="PlasticBlue"
                                    Width="100%"
                                    AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                                    KeyFieldName="ModelId"
                                    ViewStateMode="Disabled">
                                    <Columns>
                                        <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn Caption="UPC" UnboundType="Boolean" VisibleIndex="0" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right">
                                            <DataItemTemplate>
                                                <dx:ASPxCheckBox
                                                    ID="UpcASPxCheckBox" OnInit="UpcASPxCheckBox_Init"
                                                    runat="server">
                                                </dx:ASPxCheckBox>
                                            </DataItemTemplate>
                                        </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
                                        <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn Caption="MPC" UnboundType="Boolean" VisibleIndex="1" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right">
                                            <DataItemTemplate>
                                                <dx:ASPxCheckBox
                                                    ID="MpcASPxCheckBox" OnInit="MpcASPxCheckBox_Init"
                                                    runat="server">
                                                </dx:ASPxCheckBox>
                                            </DataItemTemplate>
                                        </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
                                        <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn Caption="Quantity" FieldName="Quantity" VisibleIndex="2" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right">
                                            <DataItemTemplate>
                                                <dx:ASPxSpinEdit
                                                    ID="QuantityASPxSpinEdit"
                                                    runat="server"
                                                    MinValue="0"
                                                    DecimalPlaces="0"
                                                    SpinButtons-ShowIncrementButtons="true"
                                                    OnInit="QuantityASPxSpinEdit_Init"
                                                    Width="90px"
                                                    HorizontalAlign="Right"
                                                    Text='<%# Eval("Quantity") %>'>
                                                </dx:ASPxSpinEdit>
                                            </DataItemTemplate>
                                        </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
                                        <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn Caption="Brand" FieldName="BrandCode" VisibleIndex="3" />
                                        <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn Caption="Model" FieldName="ModelCode" VisibleIndex="4" />
                                        <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn Caption="Description" FieldName="Description" VisibleIndex="5" />
                                    </Columns>
                                    <SettingsLoadingPanel Mode="Disabled" />
                                    <SettingsText EmptyDataRow="No Records" />
                                    <SettingsPager Mode="ShowAllRecords" />
                                    <Settings ShowVerticalScrollBar="false" ShowColumnHeaders="true" />
                                    <SettingsBehavior
                                        AllowSelectSingleRowOnly="false"
                                        EnableRowHotTrack="false"
                                        AllowFocusedRow="false" />
                                </dx:ASPxGridView>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <dx:ASPxPopupControl ID="ConfirmPopupControl"
                        ClientInstanceName="ConfirmPopupClientControl"
                        PopupAction="None"
                        runat="server"
                        EnableAnimation="False"
                        EncodeHtml="false"
                        ShowHeader="true"
                        ShowFooter="false"
                        Modal="true"
                        PopupVerticalAlign="WindowCenter"
                        PopupHorizontalAlign="WindowCenter"
                        ShowShadow="true"
                        CloseAction="CloseButton"
                        ShowPageScrollbarWhenModal="true"
                        Theme="Office2010Blue"
                        RenderMode="Lightweight">
                        <ContentCollection>
                            <dx:PopupControlContentControl ID="ConfirmPopupControlContentControl" runat="server"
                                SupportsDisabledAttribute="True">
                                <div class="dialog" style="width: 400px;">
                                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td style="padding: 5px;">
                                                <dx:ASPxPanel ID="MessageASPxPanel" ClientInstanceName="MessageASPxClientPanel" runat="server" Width="100%">
                                                    <PanelCollection>
                                                        <dx:PanelContent ID="PanelContent2" runat="server">
                                                            <span id="ConfirmMessageSpan" runat="Server"></span>
                                                        </dx:PanelContent>
                                                    </PanelCollection>
                                                </dx:ASPxPanel>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td align="right">
                                                <dx:ASPxButton ID="ConfirmButtonOk" runat="server" Text="Ok" AutoPostBack="false"
                                                    Height="28px" Width="100px" ForeColor="White" Font-Bold="true" Theme="RedWine">
                                                    <ClientSideEvents Click="function(s, e) { ConfirmPopupClientControl.Hide();}"></ClientSideEvents>
                                                </dx:ASPxButton>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                            </dx:PopupControlContentControl>
                        </ContentCollection>
                        <Border BorderStyle="None"></Border>
                    </dx:ASPxPopupControl>
                </table>
                <dx:ASPxHiddenField ID="PageData" ClientInstanceName="PageDataClient" runat="server"></dx:ASPxHiddenField>
            </dx:PanelContent>
        </PanelCollection>
    </dx:ASPxCallbackPanel>
```

**JS:**

```
function onUPCSelectAll(s, e) {
    $('[id*="selectAllUPCCheckBox"]').each(function () {
        eval($(this)[0].id).SetChecked(s.GetChecked());
    });
};

function onMPCSelectAll(s, e) {
    $('[id*="selectAllMPCCheckBox"]').each(function () {
        eval($(this)[0].id).SetChecked(s.GetChecked());
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You select all checkboxes' Ids start with lower case `s` and you're using a capital `S` in the jQuery selector.

Change the code to:

```
function onUPCSelectAll(s, e) {
             $('[id*="selectAllUPCCheckBox"]').each(function () {
                 eval($(this)[0].id).SetChecked(s.GetChecked());
             });
         };

         function onMPCSelectAll(s, e) {
             $('[id*="selectAllMPCCheckBox"]').each(function () {
                 eval($(this)[0].id).SetChecked(s.GetChecked());
             });
         };
```

The selector is case sensitive.

Comment: My fault... That casing will get you every time.... I got a DevExpress specific error this time. I'll edit my post and up you a vote. Thanks....